# cast sys.argv into integer

Tags: python, loops, casting

I'm trying to loop through list of arguments passed by the prompt in calling the function in python I want to get the sys.argv[1] as integer not string

this is the code i wrote in the function

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
for n in x:
    print sys.argv[1] * n
```

if i called the previous function with 5 i receive

```
    5
    55
    555
    5555
    55555
```

how can i receive

```
5
25
125
625
```

any ideas what can be the solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse String to Float or Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys
x=[1,2,3,45]
try:
    for n in x:
        print int(sys.argv[1]) * n
except IndexError:
    print "No argument were passed to the program"
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

simply by doing this

```
x=[1,2,3,45]
for n in x:
    print int(sys.argv[1]) * n
```

but be careful this solution will blow up if you pass anything that can't be casted into a string or if you are not passing anything. So you probably want to catch any exceptions with a `try` and `except` block.

Comment: it will be better if you use try: except here